# In PyGTK, what's a good way of displaying an image in a GUI?

Tags: python, gtk, png, pygtk

I have a PyGTK GUI that has a gtk.Table.

Pressing one button will generate a PNG file.

I can show the PNG file in the GUI by adding it somewhere in the table and calling the main window's show_all method again.

Is there a better way? What if I want to show more than one PNG file at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of gtk.Image, gtk.HBox (or VBox), and maybe gtk.ScrolledWindow if you plan on showing a lot of images.  Just create a new gtk.Image, set the image using `set_from_file`, then call `pack_end` on the box to display it.

Comment: I found that [`gtk.image_new_from_file('path/to/image')`](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkimage.html#function-gtk--image-new-from-file) worked pretty well too.